# How to interpret A:B in linear regression? How to calculate A:B

Tags: r, regression, interaction

In linear regression we can use A:B to show the first order interaction of variable A and B.
But it is hard to know what effect was caused by A and what was caused by B.
So I want to understand how exactly A:B worked

Answer (score 5):

> it is hard to know what effect was caused by A and what was caused by
>   B

Actually it is not hard, but impossible. First, interaction term in regression tells you on effect of A *and* B together, rather then about their individual effects. Second, regression per se does not tell you anything about causality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how the first order interaction was calculated?

Answer (score 2):

In R syntax A:B includes $A \times B$ in the regression model so

```
lm(y~A+B+A:B,data=mydata)
```

is fitting
$$
Y=\beta_0+\beta_1A+\beta_2B+\beta_3AB+\epsilon
$$
There is a discussion of this in the book "An Introduction to Statistical Learning" by James *et al*.

Comment: More precisely: it's $A\times B$ or if both A and B are discrete, it's all combinations of pairs of values of A and B that were found in data. The resulting model matrix is obtained through `model.matrix` function.